# Change header for every group in datagrid wpf

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid, grouping

I have a datagrid in which I have grouped the rows according to the author.

I have bound the datagrid with collection of Author class objects,
where Author class have three properties as Book, Publication and Number of copies which would correspond to the columns in the group in datagrid.

My problem is I want to display the sum of 'Number of copies' for that group for each author. What I'm not getting is how shall I calculate the sum since it is for a group and not for each object or total datagrid.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Strange that no one has answered this, and its probably too late for @Archie, or more likely he has found the answer long ago.  But here goes anyway:

```
<GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Expander Loaded="GroupHeaderExpander_Loaded">
                        <Expander.Header>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="Author: "/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text=" "/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}"
                                           FontStyle="Italic"/>
                                <TextBlock Text=" Books" FontStyle="Italic"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Expander.Header>
                        <ItemsPresenter>

                        </ItemsPresenter>
                    </Expander>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
```

ItemCount will give you the number of items in each group.

HTH

Comment: I don't think that was his question. `ItemCount` will display the number of books by each author; what he wants is the total number of copies sold, i.e., the sum of the "copies sold" property for all books in each group. I've posted a similar question today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13646477/accessing-items-for-wpf-datagrid-group-header