# Accessing items for WPF DataGrid group header

Tags: wpf, datagrid, header

I have a collection of objects that is displayed in a grouped WPF `DataGrid`. There are two item properties that will be the same for all items in each group, and I want to put both of them in the group header. I can show the property that's used for grouping with the `Name` binding, but how do I show the other one? I don't see any way to access the grouped items.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Items** property of the group item. You will probably need a value converter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom Expander.Header and properties of **Items[0]** element (for example **Items[0].GroupName** and **Items[0].GroupKey**).

As you said the two item properties are the same for each row in the group, so the first row will contain what you need. The group should have at least one element in it, so there won't be out of range exception.

```
<DataGrid.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Expander>
                                <Expander.Header>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                                                   VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                                   Text="{Binding Items[0].GroupName}"/>
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                                                   VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                                   Text="{Binding Items[0].GroupKey}"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Expander.Header>
                                <Expander.Content>
                                    <ItemsPresenter/>
                                </Expander.Content>
                            </Expander>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
    </GroupStyle>
</DataGrid.GroupStyle>
```